# Number of line rows affects box position

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where the number of line rows affects a box position. The more rows I have, the worse is it displaying.

The HTML I'm working with

```
<div class="block">
    <img alt="*" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="*" />
    <h2>Nameasdasd asd asdf wsd fgW</h2>    
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.block
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 13px 13px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url(/Media/PIE.htc);
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f00;
}

.block img { height: 70px; width: 70px; display: block; margin: 0 auto 10px auto; }
.block h2 { font-size: 12px; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: 'Arial'; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3GVTK/2/

I've never encountered this problem before.

Edit: Thanks for all the response and solutions! All of them are valid and works (as of now).
I'm going to stick with Blazemongers solution as it doesn't have any side-effects for the current layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the css for your `.block` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/tsRKG/

If you look at your fiddle's blocks in a wide screen, you may notice that they're aligned to the last line of text. This is what `baseline` means, which is the [default vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add following property to `.block` css class

```
float: left;
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/3GVTK/4/

Comment: This has other consequences to the layout that OP will likely want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

remove `display:inline-block;` and add `float:left;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GVTK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

just add `display:inline-table` to `block h2` in your css

like

```
.block h2 { font-size: 12px; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: 'Arial'; display:inline-table }
```

you'll need to make sure, that the kitten's name is not overly long